# How to change the shaded color of the \rule{...}{...} command?

Tags: color, rules

To change the shaded color of the `\rule{...}{...}` command, one solution is

```
\textcolor‎{‎blue‎}{\rule{2cm}{2cm}}‎
```

but I want to know how can I directly change the color of this command globally?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could do

```
\makeatletter
\let\old@rule\@rule
\def\@rule[#1]#2#3{\textcolor{blue}{\old@rule[#1]{#2}{#3}}}
\makeatother
```

But it may be better to instead define a new `\colorrule` command and use that instead, as you may find `\rule` is used in unexpected places so if you redefine it you may be changing more than you want to change.

---

If you need to override this sometimes it's probably better to use a colour such as `rulecolor` rather than `blue` that you can (re)define when needed:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{color}

\makeatletter
\let\old@rule\@rule
\def\@rule[#1]#2#3{\textcolor{rulecolor}{\old@rule[#1]{#2}{#3}}}
\makeatother

\definecolor{rulecolor}{named}{Blue}

\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\rule{1cm}{1cm}

\bigskip

\rule{.1cm}{1cm}

\bigskip

{\definecolor{rulecolor}{named}{Red}\rule{1cm}{1cm}}

\bigskip

\rule{1cm}{1cm}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please tell me where I can find the original definition of the `rule` command? I'm just curious about it.

Comment: I got it from latex.ltx  \def\rule{\@ifnextchar[\@rule{\@rule[\z@]}}
 \def\@rule[#1]#2#3{%
   \leavevmode
   \hbox{%
     \setlength\@tempdima{#1}%
     \setlength\@tempdimb{#2}%
     \setlength\@tempdimc{#3}%
     \advance\@tempdimc\@tempdima
     \vrule\@width\@tempdimb\@height\@tempdimc\@depth-\@tempdima}}

Comment: So where is the definition of the black color? Why doesn't  this definition have any definition for the black color?

Comment: TeX itself has no knowledge of colour, rules and font cgyphs are just black and white, colour is implemented by telling the ps (or pdf or other) driver separate;y to switch the current colour) A TeX rule is not really "black" it is just a rule.

Comment: A problem with this implementation is that if the user wants to change color to say red (from blue) for a single rule, on a case-by-case basis, the \textcolor{red}{\rule{...}{...}} no longer works.

Comment: @ADP true but you could locally redefine the colour, see updated answer.

Comment: LaTeX is so fiddly sometimes, makes me want to use notepad and hand a report to someone in plain text.

Answer (score 18):

The easiest alternative is:

```
    \textcolor{blue}{\rule{2cm}{2cm}}
```

If you want to define your own command, you can put this in the preamble or latter to change the color as you go.

```
    \newcommand{\myRule}[3][black]{\textcolor{#1}{\rule{#2}{#3}}}
```

and use e.g.:

```
    \myRule{1cm}{1cm}

    \myRule[red]{1cm}{1cm}

    \myRule[blue]{1cm}{1cm}
```

And if you want to fix the color throughout your document, try:

```
\newcommand{\myRule}[3]{%
    \textcolor{red}{\rule{#2}{#3}} %change red to blue, green black whatever.
}
```

Comment: It is better to use `\textcolor` as in the MWE than `\color` using `\color` can badly affect the position of the rule.

Comment: Yeah I spose. Cheers ill change it.