# How to colour \hrule

Tags: spacing, color, rules

I am trying to display a coloured `\hrule`.

[This discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/yxZslC64PTU) implies wrapping the `\hrule` in a `\textcolor` should do, but that adds an ugly extra vertical space above the `\hrule`.

Other questions on [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com), such as [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192197/colored-horizontal-line-between-two-text), or [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88502/how-to-change-the-shaded-color-of-the-rule-command), deal with coloring `\rule` rather than `\hrule`, but `\rule` already produces that extra vertical space even without `\textcolor`.

MWE with the original `\hrule` and two unsuccessful attempts to colour it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

abc%
\vskip 1mm%
\hrule

abc%
\vskip 1mm%
\textcolor{red}{\hrule}

abc%
\vskip 1mm%
\rule{\textwidth}{.1mm}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: output of the MWE source: the two attempts to colour the line include an extra vertical space]

I know I could probably use the hack of inserting a negative `\vskip` to remove a `\baselineskip` offset, but I am looking for a clean way of colouring a `\hrule` that does not involve such a workaround.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try `{\color{red}\hrule}` -- you need the `{...}` around `\color` etc. to prevent the color leaking into other parts of the document.

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

abc%
\vskip 1mm%
\hrule

abc%
\vskip 1mm%
{\color{red}\hrule}
%\textcolor{red}{\hrule}

abc%
\vskip 1mm%
\rule{\textwidth}{.1mm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit** Here's some improvement

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\NewDocumentCommand{\colorrule}{O{.4pt}m}{%
  {\color{#2}\hrule height#1}%
}

\begin{document}

abc%
\vskip 1mm%
\hrule

% Now a blue rule
\colorrule{blue}
abc%
\vskip 1mm%
\foreach \x in {Red4,Red3,Red2,Red1,orange,yellow,LightBlue1,LightBlue2,LightBlue3,LightBlue4,blue,green,brown} {%
\colorrule[2pt]{\x}
}

abc%
\vskip 1mm%
\rule{\textwidth}{.1mm}

\end{document}
```

[image]