# Color of \hrule

Tags: color, rules

I made this LaTeX function:

```
\newcommand{\Hrule}[2]{\vspace{#1}\hrule\vspace{#2}}
```

Now, I'd like to edit this function in this way: I want add a #3 in whose specify the color of this `\Hrule`.

And I want add a #4 to declare the thickness of `\hrule`.

Is it possible?

For example if I write `\Hrule{2mm}{2mm}{red}{2.5mm}` I would obtain a red `\hrule` ... .

Must I provide a minimum MWE?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Did you heard about `\rule`?

Comment: Yes, I did... Why?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270900/how-to-colour-hrule --- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88502/how-to-change-the-shaded-color-of-the-rule-command

Comment: To answer your last question: yes you should. It makes it much easier for everyone to test your problem and a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `\par\addvspace` rather than `\vspace` at the beginning.

Next, you can start a group to set the color. The default value of the optional argument is `.` that in `xcolor` stands for the current color.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\Hrule}[3][.]{%
  \par\addvspace{#2}%
  \begingroup\color{#1}%
  \hrule
  \endgroup
  \addvspace{#3}%
}


\begin{document}

Some text

\Hrule{3pt}{1pt}

Some other text

\Hrule[red!40]{3pt}{1pt}

Some other text

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to add another argument to set the thickness you can do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\Hrule}[4][.]{%
  \par\addvspace{#2}%
  \begingroup\color{#1}%
  \hrule height #4
  \endgroup
  \addvspace{#3}%
}


\begin{document}

Some text

\Hrule{3pt}{1pt}{0.4pt}

Some other text

\Hrule[red!40]{3pt}{1pt}{2pt}

Some other text

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, using four arguments is error prone, so I suggest a key-value based approach.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\Hrule}{m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { puck/hrule } { #1 }
  \par\addvspace{\l_puck_hrule_before_skip}
  \color{\l_puck_hrule_color_tl}
  \hrule height \l_puck_hrule_thickness_dim
  \addvspace{\l_puck_hrule_after_skip}%
  \group_end:
}

\keys_define:nn { puck/hrule }
 {
  before .skip_set:N = \l_puck_hrule_before_skip,
  after  .skip_set:N = \l_puck_hrule_after_skip,
  thickness .dim_set:N = \l_puck_hrule_thickness_dim,
  thickness .initial:n = 0.4pt,
  color .tl_set:N = \l_puck_hrule_color_tl,
  color .initial:n = .,
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

Some text

\Hrule{before=3pt,after=1pt}

Some other text

\Hrule{color=red!40,before=3pt,after=1pt,thickness=2pt}

Some other text

\end{document}
```

The output is the same as in the previous picture.

#### Comparison between my solution and Sergio Llorente's

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\HruleEgreg}[4][.]{%
  \par\addvspace{#2}%
  \begingroup\color{#1}%
  \hrule height #4
  \endgroup
  \addvspace{#3}%
}
\newcommand{\HruleSergio}[4]{%
  \par\noindent\vspace{#1}%
  {\color{#3}\rule{\columnwidth}{#4}}% \columnwidth instead of \textwidth
  \par\vspace{#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Egreg}

\medskip

Some text

\HruleEgreg{3pt}{1pt}{0.4pt}

Some other text

\HruleEgreg[red!40]{3pt}{1pt}{2pt}

Some other text

\newpage

\textbf{Sergio}

\medskip

Some text

\HruleSergio{3pt}{1pt}{black}{0.4pt}

Some other text

\HruleSergio{3pt}{1pt}{red!40}{2pt}

Some other text

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can see that the amount of spacing with my solution is *exactly* what's requested.

Comment: Thank you **egreg**, but the previous answer is easier then yours.

Comment: @Puck You mean that you prefer a version where you *don't* control the spaces? I added a comparison.

Comment: Thank you, but at line **\keys_define:nn { puck/hrule }**, Overlaef gives me an error because the "_" after \keys. How can I solv it? Thank you again

Comment: @Puck Add `\usepackage{xparse}`

Comment: Already done, but is it normal that Overleaf emphasizes the "_" in pink?

Comment: @Puck Ask them.

Comment: Nice solution. Thank you for the explanation. Why is better use `\begingroup...\engroup` than `{...}`? and Why you prefer `addvspace` rather than `vspace`?

Comment: @SergioLlorente There's not such a great difference in this particular case as regards to the group delimiters. If this is followed by something else that uses `\addvspace` (lists, section titles,…) the largest of the two spaces will be used.

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
\newcommand{\Hrule}[4]{\vspace{#1}{\color{#3}\rule{\textwidth}{#4}}\vspace{#2}}
```

Note that you must use `color` or `xcolor` package.

Note also that this command may have an unexpected behaviour if you use it without start a new paragraph. Usually the line is going to break always the paragraph, so you can use:

```
\newcommand{\Hrule}[4]{\par\noindent\vspace{#1}{\color{#3}\rule{\textwidth}{#4}}\par\vspace{#2}}
```

Comment: Perfect, Thank you very much